# Best Sets of Physics Lecture Notes and Articles

Tags: resource-recommendations, big-list

This post is inspired by this [math.se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302023/best-sets-of-lecture-notes-and-articles).

Let me start by apologizing if there is another thread on phys.se that subsumes this.

I often find that I learn best from sets of lecture notes and short articles. There are three particular reasons that make me feel this way.

1. Lecture notes and articles often times take on a very delightful informal approach. They generally take time to bring to the reader's attention some interesting side fact that would normally be left out of a standard textbook (lest it be too big). Lecture notes and articles are where one generally picks up on historical context, overarching themes (the "birds eye view"), and neat interrelations between subjects.
2. It is the informality that often allows writers of lecture notes or expository articles to mention some "trivial fact" that every textbook leaves out. Whenever I have one of those moments where a definition just doesn't make sense, or a theorem just doesn't seem right it's invariably a set of lecture notes that sets everything straight for me. People tend to be more honest in lecture notes, to admit that a certain definition or idea confused them when they first learned it, and to take the time to help you understand what finally enabled them to make the jump.
3. Often times books are very outdated. It takes a long time to write a book, to polish it to the point where it is ready for publication. Notes often times are closer to the heart of research, closer to how things are learned in the modern sense.

It is because of reasons like this that I find myself more and more carrying around a big thick manila folder full of stapled together articles and why I keep making trips to Staples to get the latest set of notes bound.

So, if anyone knows of any set of lecture notes, or any expository articles that fit the above criteria, please do share!

I'll start:

**People/Places who have a huge array of fantastic notes:**

['t Hooft](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html)

[John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/QG.html)

**The *Feynman* lectures on Physics:**

[The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume I: mainly mechanics, radiation, and heat.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_toc.html)

[The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II: mainly electromagnetism and matter.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_toc.html)

[The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume III: quantum mechanics.](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_toc.html)

**Introductory Courses**

- **Introductory Classical Mechanics**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/301/301.pdf
2. http://space.wccnet.edu/~gkapp/
3. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01-physics-i-classical-mechanics-fall-1999/
4. http://academics.smcvt.edu/abrizard/Classical_Mechanics/Notes_070707.pdf
5. http://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dleen/mathsoc/pdf/Notes.pdf

- **Optics and Thermodynamics &  Electromagnetism**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/316/316.pdf
2. http://seagull.ukzn.ac.za/~mukaror/
3. http://www.sicyon.com/resources/library/pdf/optics.pdf

- **Waves and Oscillations**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves.pdf
2. http://www.ma.hw.ac.uk/~bernd/F12MS3/
3. http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/OscWavesIndex.htm

- **Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/statmech.pdf
2. http://www.spms.ntu.edu.sg/PAP/courseware/statmech.pdf
3. http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys603/kelly/
4. http://stp.clarku.edu/notes/

- **Electronics**

1. http://openbookproject.net/electricCircuits/
2. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/music-and-theater-arts/21m-380-music-and-technology-live-electronics-performance-practices-spring-2011/lecture-notes/
3. http://zebu.uoregon.edu/~rayfrey/432/DigitalNotes.pdf
4. http://courseware.ee.calpoly.edu/~jzhang/EE112/
5. http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee130/sp07/lecture.html
6. http://www.engr.sjsu.edu/kghadiri/EE122/Class_notes.htm
7. http://www.cramster.com/course-introduction-lecture-note-r30-6638.aspx

- **Computational Physics**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/329.pdf
2. http://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/CourseWare/EssentialMathematica/
3. http://www.cmth.ph.ic.ac.uk/people/a.mackinnon/Lectures/compphys/
4. http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/numerical.html

- **Introductory Quantum Mechanics**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/qmech.pdf
2. http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/home.html
3. http://walet.phy.umist.ac.uk/QM/QM.pdf
4. Video:  http://physicsstream.ucsd.edu/courses/spring2003/physics130a/
5. http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes.pdf
6. http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/quantum-entanglements/

- **Classical And Quantum Optics**

1. http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/ap216/lectures/lectures.html
2. http://atomoptics.uoregon.edu/~dsteck/teaching/optics/

(from my Blog http://quantizd.blogspot.com)

So my goal is to ameliorate this list by adding more resources.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not follow our [book question policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed).

Comment: @Hunter Any policy can be changed if a proposal is put forth and agreed upon by enough people. Head on over to Meta and start the conversation if you would like to make efforts in that direction. I would caution though that popularity doesn't really mean it should be on (or off) topic... There's many questions that have attracted a large amount of attention that are not on-topic.

Comment: @Hunter Even if you don't have a concrete proposal, you can get the ball rolling and see if others can contribute a policy. You can get started by reading related meta conversations such as [why big-lists are discouraged](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4044/why-exactly-are-big-list-questions-discouraged-shouldnt-the-faq-say-this-promi) and [good list, bad list](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list) and seeing what you like or don't like there and how to incorporate the changes you would want to see.

Comment: Repeat after me: **THIS IS NOT QUORA**

Comment: This is currently being [discussed on meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/big-list-resource-questions).

Answer (score 5):

**UPPER DIVISION COURSES**

- **Mathematical Physics**

1. http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/undergrad/ughandbook/year2/ma231/
2. http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/phy311/mathphysbook/
3. http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0344/
4. http://www.dms.uaf.edu/~rybkin/MathPhysicsLectureNotes.pdf
5. http://www.teorfys.uu.se/people/minahan/Courses/Mathmeth/notes.pdf
6. http://infohost.nmt.edu/~iavramid/notes/mathphys.pdf
7. http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~jochen/methoden/outline.html
8. http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/listing.php?category=48
9. http://www.freebookcentre.net/Physics/Mathematical-Physics-Books.html
10. Mathematical methods for physicists:  http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nearing/mathmethods/

- **Classical Mechanics**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton.pdf
2. http://www.phys.psu.edu/~lammert/419/notes.html
3. http://www.physto.se/~ingemar/anmek.pdf
4. http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~rollinsr/phys605/
5. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.htm
6. http://www.courses.fas.harvard.edu/~phys16/2004_lectures/
7. http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~golwala/ph106ab/ph106ab_notes.pdf
8. http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~maloney/451/
9. Super Rigorous Treatment of Lagrangian Mechanics -http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/teaching/math439/pdf/439notes.pdf
10. Free Advanced text on Classical Mechanics (More advanced than Goldstein) -http://ipparco.roma1.infn.it/pagine/deposito/2007/elements.pdf
11. http://www.phys.psu.edu/~lammert/419/notes.html
12. Kip Thorne's Applications of Classical Physics (Advanced) :http://www.pma.caltech.edu/Courses/ph136/yr2008/text.html
13. http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/classical-mechanics/

- **Classical Electromagnetism**

1. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/em.html
2. http://monopole.ph.qmw.ac.uk/~bill/emt/LecNotes.html
3. http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/teach/module_home/px436/notes
4. http://www-solar.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~alan/MT3601/Fundamentals/Fundamentals.html
5. http://teacher.nsrl.rochester.edu/phy122/Lecture_Notes/Index.html
6. Video of Landau Level :  http://vubeam.pa.msu.edu/lectures/phy962/962d/electrodynamics/
7. http://www4.wittenberg.edu/maxwell/
8. http://www.plasma.uu.se/CED/Book/
9. E.M notes of Jackson level - http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/504/lects.shtml
10. http://physweb.bgu.ac.il/COURSES/Electro1_Gedalin/electro1_notes.html
11. http://faculty.uml.edu/cbaird/courses.html

- **Solid State physics**

1. http://physics.unl.edu/~tsymbal/teaching/SSP-927/index.shtml
2. http://www.physics.ucla.edu/~nayak/solid_state.pdf
3. http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/condmat2012/LectureNotes2012.pdf
4. http://www.physics.udel.edu/~bnikolic/teaching/phys624/lectures.html
5. http://www.wmi.badw.de/teaching/Lecturenotes/

- **Plasma Physics**

1. http://physweb.bgu.ac.il/COURSES/PlasmaGedalin/introplasma.pdf
2. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/plasma.html
3. http://www.freebookcentre.net/Physics/Plasma-Physics-Books.html

- **Nuclear Physics**

1. http://www.nuceng.ca/igna/physicsfull.htm
2. http://holbert.faculty.asu.edu/eee460/eee460.html
3. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-101-applied-nuclear-physics-fall-2006/lecture-notes/

- **Atomic Physics**

1. http://nd.edu/~johnson/Publications/book.pdf
2. http://www.nat.vu.nl/~wimu/Atom.html
3. http://www.freebookcentre.net/Physics/Atomic-Physics-Books.html
4. http://uqu.edu.sa/files2/tiny_mce/plugins/filemanager/files/4282179/atomic2.pdf

- **Particle Physics**

1. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-811-particle-physics-ii-fall-2005/lecture-notes/
2. http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1271/
3. http://www.hep.lu.se/courses/fyst17-fkf050/2002/pp-notes.pdf
4. http://pi.physik.uni-bonn.de/~brock/teaching/atpp_ss10/
5. http://physicslearning2.colorado.edu/tasi/tasi_2011/tasi_2011.htm

- **Statistical Mechanics and Thermal Physics**

1. http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~sethna/StatMech/EntropyOrderParametersComplexity.pdf
2. http://micro.stanford.edu/~caiwei/me334/
3. http://www.nd.edu/~powers/ame.20231/notes.pdf
4. http://cs.physics.sunysb.edu/verbaarschot/html/lectures/phy306-05/notes.html
5. http://me.queensu.ca/Courses/346/Notes.html
6. http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0568
7. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-044-statistical-physics-i-spring-2008/lecture-notes/
8. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2008/lecture-notes/

- **Quantum Mechanics**

1. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2006/lecture-notes/
2. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-322-quantum-theory-ii-spring-2003/lecture-notes/
3. Classical and Quantum Mechanics via Lie algebras - http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019
4. http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/#lecture
5. http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0605180
6. http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~lerdos/SS09/QM/
7. http://www.pieter-kok.staff.shef.ac.uk/index.php?nav=teaching&sub=quantum
8. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/qm.html
9. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/QM/fall-course.pdf
10. Numerical methods in QM: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-schroe/schroe.pdf

- **Quantum Field Theory**

1. http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html : Q.F.T Lecture Notes that became a book
2. HUGE comprehensive Q.F.T book :  http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/Fields3.pdf
3. Quantum Fields in Curved Space Time : https://6157258207063399106-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/winitzki/sergei-winitzkis-files/QFTCS_course.pdf
4. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html
5. http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.5013
6. http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/notes.html
7. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-238-geometry-and-quantum-field-theory-fall-2002/lecture-notes/

- **Quantum Electrodynamics**

1. http://sandman.berkeley.edu/129A/QED.pdf
2. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/six.pdf
3. http://www.hep.man.ac.uk/u/forshaw/NorthWest/QED.pdf
4. http://www.hep.phys.soton.ac.uk/hepwww/staff/D.Ross/ft1/ft115.pdf
5. http://authors.library.caltech.edu/3523/1/FEYpr49c.pdf

- **Quantum Chromodynamics**

1. http://www.phys.ethz.ch/~pheno/QCDcourse/
2. http://www.nikhef.nl/~h24/qcdcourse/
3. http://web.mit.edu/redingtn/www/netadv/hep-qcd.html
4. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0508242

- **Condensed Matter Physics**

1. http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/winter2010/physics211b/LECTURES/211_COURSE.pdf
2. http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/tp3.html
3. http://folk.uio.no/dragos/Solid/FYS230-Exercises.html
4. http://people.umass.edu/dinsmore/Phys850f04/notes.html
5. http://physics.ucsc.edu/~josh/233.09/index.html

- **Special Theory Of Relativity**

1. http://www.phys.vt.edu/~takeuchi/relativity/
2. http://www.cabrillo.edu/~jmccullough/Physics/Special_Relativity.html
3. http://sandman.berkeley.edu/129A/relativity.pdf
4. http://www.lecture-notes.co.uk/susskind/special-relativity/
5. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special_Relativity
6. http://www.mathpages.com/rr/rrtoc.htm
7. http://cosmo.nyu.edu/hogg/sr/

- **General Theory of Relativity**

1. http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March01/Carroll3/Carroll_contents.html
2. http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/
3. Intro to Differential Geometry and General Relativity -http://people.hofstra.edu/Stefan_Waner/RealWorld/pdfs/DiffGeom.pdf
4. Oxford General Relativity Lectures -  http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/nwoodh/gr/index.html
5. More General Relativity -  http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/lecturesGR.pdf
6. University of Warwick General Relativity -  http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/teach/module_home/px436/notes
7. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/gr.html
8. http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/genrel_2010.pdf
9. http://www.itp.uzh.ch/courses/mayer/GR2011/
10. http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~hartle/
11. http://www.phy.syr.edu/research/relativity/rel-link.html
12. http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/relativity.html
13. http://www.mth.uct.ac.za/~cwh/goldies.html
14. http://www.luth.obspm.fr/IHP06/
15. http://axion.physics.ubc.ca/hyperspace/

- **Cosmology**

1. http://christian.vonschultz.se/forelant/gravitation_and_cosmology/
2. http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmolog.htm
3. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/people/g.w.gibbons/
4. http://cosmology-lectures.angelfire.com/
5. http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5158
6. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0101003/
7. http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px389/
8. http://www.lsw.uni-heidelberg.de/users/mcamenzi/CosmoVorl.html

- **High Energy Physics**

1. Standard Model : http://www.nu.to.infn.it/Standard_Model/
2. European School of High-energy Physics : http://arxiv.org/html/1202.1629v1
3. https://www.kvi.nl/~brandenburg/accelera.htm
4. http://cdsagenda5.ictp.it/full_display.php?ida=a02258
5. http://www.helsinki.fi/~slehti/ComputingMethodsInHEP/ComputingMethodsInHEP.html
6. http://web.science.uu.nl/drstp/Seminars/archivesTHEP.html
7. http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5550
8. http://www.openquestions.com/oq-hep.htm
9. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0209067
10. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0403286/
11. http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/reviews/
12. http://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~krieger/phys489.html

- **String Theory**

1. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html
2. http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/stringnotes.pdf
3. http://www.physto.se/~fawad/Strings/
4. http://www.math.usm.edu/lee/strings.html
5. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9709062/
6. http://christian.vonschultz.se/forelant/string_theory/
7. http://www.nuclecu.unam.mx/~alberto/physics/stringrev.html
8. http://www.math.usm.edu/lee/strings.html
9. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0008017
10. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9709062

Answer (score 3):

Feynman also lectured on [applied math](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_1aynIanMOXbnp4dXlGOTlUNTYybldyQkx4bmRVdw/edit)
and [astronomy, astrophysics, and cosmology](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_1aynIanMOXOHVqeHJqemhSVVN4enVETllnVFpOUQ/edit?pli=1).

(These notes are not part of the Feynman lectures on physics.)

Comment: Those notes are interesting, thanks for that. But please delete this answer and edit my other answers to incorporate them, it will make the overall thread less spooky. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to add this to your answers of course, but I'm not sure it's helpful to delete the other answers, and it seems like a nonstandard use of the stackexchange functionality.

Answer (score 2):

- **Loop Quantum Gravity**

1. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0210094/
2. http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0402
3. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9710008
4. http://academics.hamilton.edu/physics/smajor/Papers/read_guide.html
5. http://www.phys.lsu.edu/faculty/pullin/gambinilaplata.pdf
6. http://cgpg.gravity.psu.edu/people/Ashtekar/articles/rovelli03.pdf
7. http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3660
8. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0404018
9. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9910079
10. http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0410054
11. http://cgpg.gravity.psu.edu/people/Ashtekar/articles.html
12. http://www.edge.org/3rd_culture/smolin03/smolin03_index.html

**Super-Symmetry Lecture Notes**

1. http://www.cpt.dur.ac.uk/~georg/ss/ss.htm
2. http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~aitchiso/susy.pdf
3. arXiv paper on ABC of Super-Symmetry -http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0905/0905.4630v1.pdf
4. http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491
5. http://www.tuhep.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~francescaB/LECTURES/LN_SUSY.html
6. http://www.christiansaemann.de/files/LecturesOnSUSY.pdf
7. http://statistics.roma2.infn.it/~fucito/appunti/derendinger.pdf

**MORE NOTES (Miscellaneous)**

- Motion Mountain Text for Physics : http://www.motionmountain.net/

- Kip Thorne's Lecture Notes, Videos and Problems On Gravitational Waves :  http://elmer.caltech.edu/ph237/

- Set Of Lecture Notes on All Physics Topics (Intro to Advanced Undergrad From U of T at Austin) : http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching.html

- Lectures on Harmonic Analysis -  http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ilaba/wolff/notes_march2002.pdf

- Tons of Course notes By John Baez -  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/QG.html  and  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/

- Tons of Course Notes BY Warren Siegel - http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/plan.html

- Lots of Presious Links By Dr. B.S Ramachandra - http://www.drbsramachandra.com/apps/links/

- Huge Number of Physics E-Books -  http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/listing.php?category=2, and http://www.freebookcentre.net/Physics/Physics-Books-Online.html

- Analytical Mechanics -

1. http://www.physto.se/~ingemar/anmek.pdf
2. http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~rollinsr/phys605/

- David Tong's Lecture notes from Cambridge - http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics.htm

- Caltech notes -  http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~golwala/ph106ab/ph106ab_notes.pdf

- Guide To Theoretical Physics

1. http://michaelhallsmoore.com/blog/Guide_To_Theoretical_Physics
2. http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/theorist.html
3. http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019
4. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/books.html

- NPTEL Physics Courses (Some of the topics are under development) : http://www.nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=115

- MIT OCW courses : http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#physics

- http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS481/lecture.html

- James Binney's Lecture Courses : http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/lectures.html

- Foundations of Math Physics : http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/courses/cmms30/7CCMMS30.html

- Some good Notes : http://v37s3b4h7dn47s37hg1br4h7rs7n3du7s8nu.unbf.ca/~n28zb/Some%20good%20lectures%20and%20notes.html

- http://www.hepl.harvard.edu/~morii/phys151/lectures/

- Michael Fowler's Notes : http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/

- Free university lectures : http://lecturefox.com/physics/?page=1

- Lecture Notes and Reviews (Cambridge) : http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/res_lec.html

- http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/index.php?lang=e&n1=courses&n2=scripts

- http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnCardy/

- Homepage of Michael Goerz : http://michaelgoerz.net/studies/theoretical-physics.html

- http://www.jpoffline.com/mphysnotes.php

- John Preskill Lecture Notes : http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/

- http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/

- http://online.itp.ucsb.edu/online/lnotes/

- http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Physics/Education/Tutorials/

- http://users.ictp.trieste.it/~pub_off/lectures/

- http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~nrc25/tp2/index.html

- http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/books/wwwbrief?t=Lectures+Notes+in+Physics

- http://home.thep.lu.se/~bijnens/fytn04/

- http://www.dctech.com/physics/lecture_notes.php

- http://freescienceonline.blogspot.in/

- http://www.nuigalway.ie/physics/links_lectNotes.html

- http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/topcites/2010/alltime.shtml

- **RECOMMENDED PHYSICS BOOKS**

1. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Administrivia/booklist.html
2. http://www.amazon.com/Some-great-books-physics-self-study/lm/R8EJA6K1IP4J2
3. http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=53126
4. http://www.amazon.com/Physics-Major-Musts/lm/2W8A6WNYI6D3Q
5. http://www.amazon.com/best-physics-books/lm/13XQ7BUZB1DI3
6. http://michel-lussier.hubpages.com/hub/textbooks-for-the-standard-physics-curriculum
7. http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicphys.htm